# Como mudar o cursor de escrita do input?

Tags: html, css

Olá pessoal creio eu que seja algo bem simples, porém sou ainda meio leigo no HTML gostaria de saber como faço pra no momento que a pessoa clicar no input que escreva no meio da caixa ou pode ser também alguns pixel a esquerda... resumindo quero que o valor escrito fique no meio da caixa do input e não no começo.

Answer (score 1):

Basta usar os estilos de text-align para definir, direita, esquerda ou centro. Vc tb pode usar o `padding` para dar espaço dentro do `input`, nesse exemplo coloquei 5px abaixo e acima, e 15px na direita/esquerda.

Veja o exemplo

```html
  
<input type="text" style="text-align: left; padding: 5px 15px;" placeholder="esquerda">
<input type="text" style="text-align: center; padding: 5px 15px" placeholder="centro">
<input type="text" style="text-align: right; padding: 5px 15px" placeholder="direita">
```